# Нужна ли запятая в данном предложении? (9)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, предлоги, вводные-слова

подскажите пожалуйста, необходима ли запятая на месте пропуска в данном предложении и почему: Так, после посещения картинной галереи **(?)** я вдохновился стать художником.

Comment: Вдохновляются во время посещения, а не после (уже нечем вдохновляться).

Answer (score 1):

Здесь возможны **три варианта оформления предложения**, что определяется контекстом. Для ясности приведены примеры.

1. ***Так после посещения картинной галереи  я вдохновился стать художником.***  Нет запятой.

Местоименное наречие  ТАК (в роли обстоятельства образа действия) указывает на  сказанное ранее.

Автор описывает **общее впечатление** от посещения картинной галереи: интересные работы, необычные композиции и цветовые решения, увлеченность людей, их особый духовный мир.

2. **Так, после посещения картинной галереи, я вдохновился стать художником.**  Две запятые.

Местоименное наречие ТАК **конкретизируется/уточняется** обособленным  обстоятельством (как / когда / в результате чего именно / при каких обстоятельствах). Пример из Розенталя: *Вот так, походя, вопрос не решить.*  Розенталь, § 22. [Уточняющие члены предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#).

Автор описывает конкретный жанр, который произвел на него наибольшее впечатление. Например, портретная живопись, умение художника изобразить не только внешние черты, но и создать интересный психологический образ. Поэтому ему захотелось освоить именно этот вид искусства.

3. ***Так, после посещения картинной галереи  я вдохновился стать художником.*** Одна запятая.

**Вводное слово ТАК** (в начале предложения или части сложного предложения). То же, что «например».

Автор рассказывает о том, что в юности **он увлекался очень многим,** мечтал стать то писателем, то музыкантом,  то режиссером фильмов, но никак не мог остановиться на чем-то одном. Новые впечатления от встреч с творческими людьми часто меняли  желания: к примеру, после посещения выставки он захотел стать художником.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142428/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-------9).

Comment: Второе не получается. "После посещения картинной галереи" отвечает на вопрос "когда?", а не "как?"/"каким образом?". Вот правило: Уточняющие члены играют в предложении важную роль, конкретизируя то, на что указывает уточняемый член предложения. Они **всегда отвечают на один с ним вопрос**, к которому можно добавить слово “именно”. Другой источник: Уточняющим называется член предложения, **отвечающий на тот же вопрос**, что и другой член, после которого он стоит, и служащий для уточнения. И ещё один: Уточняющие члены относятся к уточняемому слову и **отвечают на тот же вопрос**.

Comment: Оно не передаёт способ вдохновения, а должно, оно передаёт время вдохновения.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, запятая не нужна, так как "после посещения картинной галереи" просто показывает время совершения действия. Ты можешь поставить "вчера" вместо "после посещения картинной галереи" и ничего в пунктуации не изменится.